# Limit access to specific CloudWatch dashboard

Tags: grafana

I was wondering if it was at all possible to limit the access to a specific CloudWatch dashboard. So we want to use data from a CloudWatch dashboard in Grafana but Grafana should only be able to read a specific dashboard and not any other dashboard.

I was having a look at IAM roles and permissions and such but it seems you can't limit access there to a single dashboard, so I was wondering if there was any way or a workaround so that I can limit an IAM user/role to a specific CloudWatch dashboard?

To clarify: I have a Lambda that provides data that is being pushed into a CloudWatch dashboard on AWS. I have re-used this lambda to populate multiple dashboards (input file and output dashboard is parameter), and I want to show the data for a specific customer in Grafana.

So:
lambda 1 reads file A and populates CloudWatch dashboard A
lambda 1 reads file B and populates CloudWatch dashboard B
lambda 1 reads file C and populates CloudWatch dashboard C

So same operation occurs but for different files and different output.

In Grafana for customer A I want to show the data of CloudWatch dashboard A, for customer B (different Grafana) I want to show the data of CloudWatch dashboard B.

So I am looking for a way to separate the data per dashboard, so if a customer changes the query in Grafana he doesn't end up seeing someone elses data.

I hope I made myself a bit clearer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana doesn't use *CloudWatch dashboard*. It uses only *CloudWatch data* and it makes own dashboards = you can't use IAM at all to limit Grafana dashboard.

Comment: What I meant was I want to limit acces to data of a specific CloudWatch dashboard.

Comment: Please update your question and provide example. It is not clear what do you really want to do.